# How to get an instance of a plugin

Tags: 8, plugins

I am attempting to use a pre-configured instance of a plugin.  The plugin is of type **@CommercePaymentGateway**.

I am currently trying to use something like:

```
/** @var PaymentGatewayManager $manager */
$manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.commerce_payment_gateway');
$manager->getInstance(['module' => 'commerce_paypal']);
```

But I'm getting the error `Error: Call to a member function getInstance() on null`.  However, using `kint()`, `$manager` is clearly an instance of `Drupal\commerce_payment\PaymentGatewayManager`.

I see what I think is the instance configuration in the config table under `commerce_payment.commerce_payment_gateway.paypal_ec`.  But that `paypal_ec` part is specific to my site.

How do I get an instance of a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, in my case, I'm asking the wrong question.  All that I need is the parent config entity (@bojanz pointed this out in slack), so I was over-complicating the issue:

```
$gateway = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('commerce_payment_gateway')->loadByProperties([
    'plugin' => 'paypal_express_checkout',
]);
```

This will return an array of gateways, get a specific one:

```
// Get the first one
$plugin = reset($gateway);
$plugin = $plugin->getPlugin();
```

Now you have the `$plugin` to be used elsewhere.